# What is the name of a technique in building your arguments stronger by downplaying it?

Tags: word-request

I remember a technique in [critical thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_thinking) that you try to downplay your own argument and steel your opponent's argument. What is the name of it?

Comment: I cannot call to mind a formal word or phrase, but what would fit is **devil's advocacy**.

Comment: Well, an extreme way of downplaying it would be to assume it's completely wrong, and then arriving at an impossible conclusion, therefore accepting your initial hypothesis as being more credible / better at explaining some phenomenon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steelmanning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh-DKbKlfag). As how philosopher Danial Dennett puts it:

> Attempt to re-express your target's position so clearly, vividly and fairly that your target says: "Thanks, I wish I'd thought of putting it that way."